# Combinatorics/ digits problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

How many ways are to arrange **exactly** two 2s and one 3 in a number n<100000.

So at first I considered the three cases where n has 3 digits, 4 digits or 5 digits.
But I think
$\binom{5}{2} \binom{3}{1} 8^3$ would cover all the cases automatically, because $8^3$ would also account for the 4 digits and 3 digits automatically, since here the first / first and second digit would allowed to be zero? Would this solution be correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Why is it $8^3$? It should be $8^2$. Otherwise it is correct.

Comment: Yes... it would be correct.  There is no reason to consider three digit or four digit separately and then add that complicated condition that the first digit can't be $0$.  Just do all numbers considered have five digits any of which could be $0$.... Your answer is correct. .... BTW this means the expression you get for considering the cases must equal this expression as well.  It might by "fun" to demonstrate that algebraically.

Comment: Oh... @MathLover is correct.  the two $2$s and the one $3$ account for $3$ of the $5$ digits (including possible leading zeros) so there are $2$ remaining digits (which each can have $8$ possible values.  So ${5\choose 2}{3\choose 1}8^{\color{red}2}$.

Comment: Thank you all very much

Comment: @fleablood: yes I thought about it as well would be fun  to consider all the cases separately and sum it up and prove that it is the same

Comment: This does mean that ${5\choose2}{3\choose 1}8^2=\underbrace{7\cdot{4\choose2}{2\choose1}\cdot8}_{\text{5 digits not starting with 3or 2}}+\underbrace{{4\choose1}{3\choose1}8^2}_{\text{5 digits starting with 2}}+\underbrace{{4\choose 2}8^2}_{\text{5 digits starting with 3}}+\underbrace{7{3\choose2}{1\choose1}}_{\text{4 digits not starting with 3 or 2}}+\underbrace{{3\choose2}8}_{\text{4 digits starting with 3}}+\underbrace{{3\choose 1}{2\choose1}8}_{\text{4 digits starting with 3}}+\underbrace{{3\choose 2}{1\choose1}}_{\text{3 digits}}$.  Might be ....interesting... to show that mathematically.